# How to align an equation with a bullet and its tag?

Tags: equations, align, numbering, environments

I have this

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $K_{1}= K_{s}(N_{yy}-N_{zz})$
\item $K_{2}= K_{s}N_{yz}$
\end{itemize}
```

But I'd like it to be displayed as in this picture:

[image]

The problem is whatever combination of environments I try with "begin align", "begin equation" or "begin itemize" gives me errors.

I need an equation flushed to the left with a bullet and following the same numbering as every other equations. :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'flalign' environment
\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{section}{1}   % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{41}

\begin{flalign}
\bullet\quad K_1 &= K_{s}(N_{yy}-N_{zz})& \\
\bullet\quad K_2 &= K_{s}N_{yz} \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that `flalign` treats a list of equations as one (`equation`) in terms of numbering?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that (and I need to clean my glasses as I overlooked the `notag` option ... )

Comment: @alchemist - (redo b/c my earlier comment had too many typos) Short answer: No. Slightly longer answer: By default, each row of an `flalign` construct gets its own equation number. To override the default, it is.necessary to issue a `\notag` (or `\nonumber`) instruction in each row that is *not* supposed to be numbered.  Hence the presence of a `\notag` directive in row 2 of the answer I posted.